# File tagging over several internal/external disks

Tags: document-indexing

I have about 10TB of documents, pictures, videos, and other misc files. I am having trouble keeping track of these files and easily locating them. I find myself often having 3 copies of an archive that may be 2GB which can be problematic.

These files are spread over 3 externals and 1 internal.
Some of these files are grouped together in a folder ( ex: "getting started with x" folder may have videos, .c files, and pdf files) which makes it difficult to simply separate them by type.

I'm looking for a way to be able to know what I have at all times to avoid the waste of space of time of reacquiring the data. Ideally I am looking for something similar to tagging. Where I can tag files and simply be able to search for them. for example the file "x" can have the tags "Malware" "Kernel" "Monitoring" "c++" "windows" and I will be able to find this file with any of these tags. I've thought about a database with files and locations, but if I move a file it will not update. Adding a tag to the file itself will be persistent. What would be the best way to go about achieving this goal?

--edit I am currently in between Windows 8.1 and Opensuse 13.1 as there are certain things I am unable to access on Opensuse alone.

Comment: When I saw the title and a new user I thought ugh this is going to be a lame question... but no I have to say it isn't. I unfortunately can't think of anything that meets your requirements but it sounds like a very useful system if it exists. (I can think of them for specific file types - ie images or audio or video)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 and more recent supports tagging and Libraries (used to be "Smart Folders). I know it's not a perfect solution, but could that meet your needs?

On Linux, you might want to look at "tmsu" (http://tmsu.org/).

Comment: More details would be better - like talk about how those could meet the OP's needs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [XYplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/). The standard license is 29.95$.

> XYplorer is a tabbed file manager for Windows. It features a powerful file search, a versatile preview, a highly customizable interface, optional dual pane, and a large array of unique ways to efficiently automate frequently recurring tasks. It's fast and light, it's innovative, and it's portable.

From http://www.xyplorer.com/

Here is a screenshot from its webpage:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may also use [Tabbles](http://tabbles.net/). It is free for personal use.

> Tagging, without the pain of tagging.
>
> Use tabbles like folders to organize your files, and like tags to search your data.
>
> Tag a file or drag’n'drop a file into a tabble. Then double click a tabble to see what’s “inside” it. Put your files, folders and URLs into several tabbles without duplicating them. Click on a file to see what it’s related to. Yet, most of the tagging is done automatically!

From http://tabbles.net/

Here is a screenshot from its webpage:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try [Elyse](http://silkwoodsoftware.com/index.html). It's free for use but limited to 30 tags.

> Elyse is a file management system which solves the major problem with traditional methods of managing large numbers files on computers: paths and folders. Storing files in Elyse eliminates the need to decide precisely where to store a file, or to subsequently find where it was stored. Any logical method of grouping and arranging files can be used. In short, you the user are given the power to impose your own logic, and change your mind as often you like with just a few clicks.

From http://silkwoodsoftware.com/

Here is a screenshot from its webpage:

[image]